# What exactly is happening during the opening titles of “Crusher Joe: The Movie” (1983)

Tags: crusher-joe

What exactly is happening during the opening titles of *Crusher Joe: The Movie* (1983)?

I am not talking about the pre-credits chase, but rather the action that happens right during the opening credits where the Crushers seem to be swooping in on an asteroid/starbase combo, burst through some airlocks and then send—what appears to be—a malfunctioning/failing part of the asteroid into space where it explodes.

Based on what is shown, I am assume that the thing exploding was some reactor connected to the starbase, but I am not clear about the action past what we see on screen. Was this an event straight out of one of the original Haruka Takachiho’s novels?

Screenshot below of the scene in question with the Crusher ships—Minerva and those other ships Alvin and Crusher Joe pilot—flying towards the hunk of rock in space.

[image: The Crusher Joe team in action!]